# Distance from the core of a characteristic function game (between a point and an n-dimensional closed convex polyhedron)

Tags: matlab, game-theory, polyhedra

In transferable utility characteristic function games (cooperative game theory), the most famous solution concept is the core of the game defined as the set of feasible payoff allocations that cannot be improved upon by any coalition. Geometrically the core is a closed convex polyhedron:
http://www.jstor.org/stable/2630190

In these game a payoff allocation is either in the core or not. The TUGlab set of tools has a command that can compute whether or not a payoff allocation is in the core or not:
http://webs.uvigo.es/mmiras/TUGlab/
But there is no command that would tell you what the exact distance of a certain payoff allocation is to the core. If there is a geometric characterization of the core as a closed convex polyhedron, then there should be a way to calculate the geometric distance between a point and that polyhedron as "distance from the core" of characteristic function. Unfortunately I have found no paper that actually shows me the formula or algorithm for computing this distance that I could implement in MATLAB.

My guess is that there may be a clue in the code by Stephen Cameron that calculates distance between two polyhedrons. But my problem should be simpler than that: just the distance between a point and a polyhedron. In the end, I need a MATLAB program that takes as input a) a characteristic function, and b) a payoff distribution, and then gives as output the distance between the payoff distribution and the core of the characteristic function. Assuming of course that the core is nonempty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complicated though the core concept may be, a geometrical translation can simplify it by an order of magnitude!

Knowing the core description as a system of inequalities, you can numerically minimize the Euclidean distance of a given point to the surface of the N-D convex polyhedron.

Assuming that the core is characterized by the system of inequalities and equalities as:

```
A.x <= b
```

and

```
Aeq.x = beq
```

(this part may not exist in all descriptions)

one can simply minimize the distance `|Cp-Gp|` where `Gp` is the coordinates of a given point and `Cp` is the point closest to Gp that satisfies the above constraints describing the core.

A simple numerical solution is using the `lsqlin` function already available in MATLAB. A single line of code would give you the distance, `D` and the position of the closest point on the convex, `Cp` as:

```
[Cp,D,residual,exitflag,output,lambda] = lsqlin(speye(N),GP,A,b,Aeq,beq);
```

Moreover, if the returned argument `residual` is negative one can conclude that `Gp` is contained within the core.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't understand why you are interested in the distance of a point 
outside of the core to the core itself, I shall give you a quick procedure of how to
get an approximation. The example below can be reproduced with my Matlab 
Game Theory Toolbox MatTuGames, which can be downloaded at the following URL:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35933-mattugames

To start with, consider the following five person game:

```
>> v=[2   0   1   0   0   0   4   2   0   0   1   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   1   0   0   2   4   1   1   1   4   1  2   4   8];
```

The Shapley value is quickly calculated through

```
>> tic;sh_v=ShapleyValue(v);toc
```

Elapsed time is 0.002676 seconds.

```
>> sh_v
```

sh_v =

```
1.7500    1.9167    1.1667    1.5000    1.6667
```

In the next step, we check whether the core exists or not

```
>> CddCoreQ(v)
```

ans =

```
 1
```

Since, the return value is one (true), the core exists for the example game. 
Furthermore, we also check on convexity, average-convexity and super-additivity

```
>> convex_gameQ(v)
```

ans =

```
 0

>> average_convexQ(v)
```

ans =

```
 0

>> super_additiveQ(v)
```

ans =

```
 0
```

None of these properties is satisfied. Next, we verify if the Shapley value belongs 
to the core.

```
>> crQ=belongToCoreQ(v,sh_v)
```

crQ =

```
 0
```

This is not the case. Thus, we use the Shapley value to compute an approximated distance to
the core. To complete, we compute the vertices of the core, this can be accomplished by

```
>> tic;crv=CddCoreVertices(v);toc
```

Elapsed time is 0.001161 seconds.

```
>> crv
```

crv =

```
 2     2     0     2     2
 4     2     0     2     0
 2     4     0     2     0
 2     2     0     4     0
 2     0     2     4     0
 4     0     2     2     0
 2     0     2     2     2
 2     0     4     2     0
 4     0     0     2     2

>> size(crv)
```

ans =

```
 9     5
```

Now, we can compute the Euclidean distance of the Shapley value to the core vertices. 
Hence, we evaluate

```
>> for k=1:size(crv), ed(k,:)=norm(sh_v-crv(k,:));  end

>> ed
```

ed =

```
1.3385
3.0754
2.9651
3.2339
3.6686
3.5296
2.1890
3.8460
3.2339
```

Single out the smallest distance value and its position is done through

```
>> [mn,id]=min(ed)


mn =

1.3385


id =

 1
```

We observe that the first core vertex in the above list has smallest distance to Shapley value. You might get a better approximation, if you choose that face with vertex

```
>> crv(id,:)
```

ans =

```
 2     2     0     2     2
```

that is closest to the Shapley value. Then compute the center of the face, which might give you a better approximation.

**Update:**

Based on the answer by Mehdi Pouragha, that gives the correct approach to use an orthogonal projection from a point outside of the core to the core itself. I present a small Matlab function to calculate the closest point of the core to an arbitrary point outside of the core.

```
function DC=CPCore(v,x,tol)
% CPCORE computes the closest point of the core to x. 
% 
%
% Usage: DC=CPCore(v,x,tol)
% Define variables:
%  output:
%  Cp       -- Closest point of the core to x.
%  D        -- The Euclidean distance between the points.
%  resid    -- The residual.
%  ef       -- Exitflag.
%  lambda   -- Containing the Lagrange multipliers.
%
%  input:
%  v        -- A Tu-Game v of length 2^n-1. 
%  x        -- The reference point from which the distance 
%              to core should be drawn.
%  tol      -- Tolerance value. Its default value is set to 10^6*eps.

if nargin<3
   tol=10^6*eps;
end

N=length(v);
[~, n]=log2(N);
S=1:N;
for k=1:n, A(:,k) = bitget(S,k)==1;end
v1(S)=v(S)-tol;
v1(N)=v(N);
A=-A;
B=-v1;
Aeq=ones(1,n);
beq=v(N);


[Cp,D,residual,exitflag,~,lambda] = lsqlin(eye(n),x,A,B,Aeq,beq);
Cp=Cp';
resid=residual';
DC=struct('Cp',Cp,'D',D,'resid',resid,'ef',exitflag,'lambda',lambda);
```

Now, we can compute the closest point of the core to the Shapley value from the above five person game by

```
>> DC=CPCore(v,sh_v)
```

The result is

```
DC = 

    Cp: [2.0000 1.6667 0.9167 2.0000 1.4167]
     D: 0.5000
 resid: [0.2500 -0.2500 -0.2500 0.5000 -0.2500]
    ef: 1
lambda: [1x1 struct]
```

Correctness can be checked out by

```
>> tol=10^7*eps;
>> belongToCoreQ(v,DC.Cp,tol)

ans =

 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your step by step answer! I hadn't realized that someone had answered this...I really appreciate it. However, If I am not mistaken, distance to the nearest vertex of the core, is not exactly distance from the core, because somewhere on the edge of the core between some vertices may be closer to our focal point than the nearest vertex. Am I right? The application for this is to compute how close or far an economy is from equilibrium. I am working on simulations of economic dynamics where knowing this is useful: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/smj.2203/abstract

Comment: Of course, the nearest vertex might not be the closest point to the Shapley value. But it should give you the face that contains the point that is closest. For this reason, I argue that it might be useful to compute the center of the face to get a better approximation. However, this might not be end of the iteration. But if you study competitive equilibria (these are NTU games not TU games), you know that these are contained in the core, from this point of view you have to find out the set of equilibria points to get an idea how close an economy is from equilibrium. What is the focal point?

Comment: The games I model are actually TU games, and the agents in the game dynamically change the game by adding value to the characteristic function, and then competing for profits which they only imperfectly find. So the characteristic function and profit vector are changing once in a while, and each time we want to know how far the current profit vector is from the core of the current characteristic function (if it has a core, and the profit vector is not in it). The focal point is usually not the Shapley value, because that is usually already in the core so distance from equilibrium is zero.

Comment: An exchange economy is a mapping from the set of agents into the space of agents' characteristics. The set of agents is assumed to be countably infinite or a continuum. For TU games n is assumed to finite, a competitive equilibrium does not exist. In your model an equilibrium point should be a kind of a Nash equilibrium (Cournot,Bertrand,Stackelberg,etc) which does not belong to the core. The core specifies in your model a set of profit vectors that cannot be blocked by a sub-coalition.

Comment: (Cont.) The characteristic function specifies for each coalition a value (profit) from which it cannot be prevented from by its opponents. Profit vectors in the core are a subject of negotiation and not of competition. However, to understand your model better I have to read it. In this respect a link to your paper would be helpful.

Comment: A link to my paper was in the first comment, also see [link](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2549003) for a review. The concept of the core in a TU characteristic function game is itself what we take as competitive equilibrium in this literature. It is sometimes empty but usually not, even with finite n. I don't need any other equilibrium concepts, I just want the distance of a profit vector from the core, when that vector is outside of the core. When it is inside, the distance is zero.